# Java deserialization lead to default values

Tags: java, serialization

So for a programming exercise I have to save data into files. I used the interface `Serializable` to save my data.

The problem occurs when I deserialize my file. When I print my object deserialized I can see all the values that have been saved but when I add this object to an arraylist and try to display this object again, all my values are set to default (defined into my superclass).

I don't know if my question is clear but if you need more information please ask.

Here is a part of my code:

```
public static void loadData(Mouse mouse, Monkey monkey, String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException{

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

    try{
        Animal animal = (Animal)ois.readObject();

    if (fileName == "Mice.ser"){
        animal = (Mouse)animal;
        mouse.setLists();
    }

    else{
        animal = (Monkey)animal;
        monkey.setLists();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){}
    ois.close();
}


public class Mouse extends Animal implements Serializable{
    protected List mouseG1 = new ArrayList();
    protected List mouseG2 = new ArrayList();

    public void setLists(){
    if (this instanceof MouseG1){
        mouseG1.add((MouseG1)this);
    }
    else{
        mouseG2.add((MouseG2)this);
    }
}
```

That's it, sorry for my english (and code) I'm a beginner (and french)

Comment: Could you add some code to the question?

Comment: We need to actually see some code. Asking for debugging help without showing us the code is like asking a detective to solve a murder case without showing him the crime scene.

Comment: Sorry I add some code up there.

Comment: First, `if (fileName == "Mice.ser")` will not work;  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java .  Second, *never* write an empty `catch` block;  at the very least, put `e.printStackTrace();` in there, so you know if something went wrong.  Third, you almost certainly should not give each `Mouse` instance its own separate List(s).

Comment: @VGR I'll argue about empty catch block, sometimes it is useful to catch for example NumberFormatException instead of checking it with other methods

Comment: @DmytroGrynets There is never a good reason to leave it empty.  If the exception is part of standard application behavior, log it at a low level, like [Level.FINE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#FINE).

Comment: @VGR Hm, good point, never though about that this way, it is really reasonable, thank you

Comment: Finally I'm restarting the code to improve it and to simplify it. Maybe it will be easier to save after the modifications. Thank you anyway !